# NFT Tutorial Downloading Hardhat Error

Tags: hardhat, alchemy

After going through the steps listed in https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-create-an-nft, I keep getting an error message when downloading Hardhat.

The three error messages are:

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/****/.npm/_logs/************_569Z-debug.log
****@Mac***** project-alchemy % npm install
```

Comment: Did you install Node.JS beforehand? You need Node.JS to run npm

Answer (score 0):

From the Alchemy Hello World [tutorial](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-create-an-nft) Step 7, this is how you can download and install Hardhat for your project:

`npm install --save-dev hardhat`

Here are the official Hardhat docs on how to install and get started:

https://hardhat.org/getting-started/#overview

---

Here are some additional resources:

Do you see any hardhat-specific errors? Here is a list of common Hardhat issues and what to do about them:

https://hardhat.org/errors/

Can you also share more details on what is contained in the debug log? And which command you were trying when you received that `could not determine executable to run` error?